# Unable to mosaic raster bands of the same region in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, mosaic, masking, scp

I am trying to mosaic the Landsat satellite imagery of an ROI to fill the masked cloud regions. For this, I am using f1023clip and f5163clip (as shown in images below).

I am trying to mosaic the two tiles with f1023clip followed by f1563clip using the 'first' operator, however, I get the following result: wherein the f1023clip area turns all black with its no data areas now filled with f1563clip tile.

If I use the 'last' operator, it only comes up with f1563clip tile, which should be that way only

How do I correct this?

I am using ArcGIS Pro, but am facing a similar problem with SCP plugin in QGIS too.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Suggest you edit your question and show how you are using the mosaic rasters tool as its not clear what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

I can see that these inputs(f1023clip and f5163clip) are a result of the clip raster function, and you have then used the Mosaic function to stitch these two clips together.  Correct me if I misunderstood.

I would rather say you should try using the recommended workflow to create and work with mosaics in ArcGIS Pro/ArcMap.

Moving ahead, you must have the entire imagery for the study area, which is not clipped, so try following the below steps to create a mosaic dataset first in ArcGIS Pro.

The demo below is using one single tool to create a mosaic that can be tested:

https://youtu.be/OBUszlQ4Pa8

If the above does give you the black mosaic output, try using the combination of create and add rasters GP tools:

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/data/imagery/creating-mosaic-datasets-wf.htm

**Note:** Once you get the correctly mosaicked imagery, go ahead with clipping it to your AOI using the Clip raster function, or [Extract by Mask GP tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/extract-by-mask.htm).

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem, the two tiles I was trying to mosaic weren't of the same format. I converted them both to float and it worked!